# Why does some HTML have large gaps in the source?

Tags: php, html

Why do some HTML pages have large gaps in the source code? I have seen this with a lot of PHP pages; when peeking at the source through Chrome dev tools I see large spaces (example below). *Why does this happen?* Does this even have to do with PHP at all? (I'm just guessing because I have only seen it on .php pages)[image]

Comment: Stupid/cheat "copy protection" to make script kiddies think there's nothing there when they use the ultra-s33kr1t "view source" hacking tool..

Comment: That's just sloppiness from the part of whomever made the page.

Comment: Theoretically there are a bunch of PHP statements that do nothing (such as `<?php maybe_do_something(); ?> {newline} <?php maybe_do_something(); ?> {newline} ...`) this might result.

Comment: and some times an empty line before or after the php script in php files

Comment: @MarcB Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a templating engine (not necessarily PHP or PHP-based) where inactive blocks (e.g. due to a falsy if condition) still add whitespace.

Take this as an example:

```
<html>
{% if false %}blah{% endif %}
{% if false %}blah{% endif %}
{% if false %}blah{% endif %}
{% if false %}blah{% endif %}
</html>
```

That contains four linebreaks (between the endif and if blocks) which will still show up in the generated HTML.